# Nested loop through list of sets

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-loops

I recently read is not a good practice to do the following:

```
for i in xrange(len(string-or-list)):
    #do something with string-or-list[i]
```

I get it. But when it comes to nested loops, I don't.

Consider a list of sets `h`. I want to eliminate all those sets that are subsets of other sets. This is what I did:

```
for x in xrange(len(h)-1,-1,-1):
    for y in xrange(x):
        if h[x] <= h[y]: h[x] = set()
        elif h[x] > h[y]: h[y], h[x] = h[x], set()
return filter(None, h)
```

What can I do to make it more pythonic? I though about using `reversed` and `enumerate`, but then I don't know how to stop the second loop to the element before `x`.
Or should I do the whole thing differently maybe?

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem by making the list of sets into a set of tuples, and then I applied

```
    return [list(s) for s in h if sum(1 for o in h if set(s) <= set(o)) <= 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most pythonic thing would be to compose a new list with the sets you want. To remove duplicates we need a helper function..

```
def uniq(seq):
    memo = []
    for i in seq:
        if i not in memo:
            memo.append(i)
            yield i
```

Then we can do what we want

```
return [s for s in uniq(h) if not any(s < o for o in h)]
```

Comment: any set is a subset of itself

Comment: not a strict subset. which is what `<` checks for.. `s < s == False`

Comment: omg, can't believe I'm so stupid ... thanks. When I first wrote the function I used another method and I couldn't use a list comprehension. But now, of course! They should take me off reputation points for this question T.T
Have a good day!

Comment: @Pigna I edited my answer to correct for the case of duplicates

Answer (score 1):

The [idea from Chad S.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34620220/674039) is good and pythonic, but reading your initial code it looks like you were looking for subsets (and not strict subsets).

Here's an approach which accounts for the usual meaning of the word subset:

```
while True:
    for s in h:
        if sum(1 for o in h if s <= o) > 1:
            h.remove(s)
            break
    else:
        # no subsets were found - we're done
        break
```

Comment: I'm guessing this might be problematic as whenever s appears in the list twice all instances will be removed. And if there are no duplicates it's the same as my solution.

Comment: Thanks! It may happen that there are duplicates. So, I guess the solution is: `return [s for s in h if sum(1 for o in set(h) if s <= o) <= 1]`?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true.  I'll modify it.

Comment: What do you want to happen to duplicates?

Comment: Any of them? or just one copy

Comment: I want just one copy